# using either ksh bash how to have performance effective way

Tags: bash, ksh

```
112345D000000000000129
123456D000000000000129
112345C000000000000129
123456C000000000000129
123456C000000000000126
```

position 2-6 is the account number

position 7-22 is the debit or credit value based on D or C in 7th position

want to sum the credit and debit value on the per account basis 
tried

```
awk '{array[substr($0,7,1)]+=substr($0,8,15)+0} END{for(i in array){print array[i]}}')"
```

but since the file is huge its taking more time is there a way we can find out this one more faster

MVCE

fileA contains the account number + other info

fileB contains the exampe above with debit credit

```
typeset -i stbal2
typeset -i endbal2
DONE=false
until $DONE; do
read s || DONE=true
accountnumber=${s:1:10} //account number
endbal=${s:26:1}        //contain + or - sign
endbal1=${s:11:15}      //balance 

endbal2=$endbal1        //strip of leading zeros
endbal3=$endbal$endbal2 //concatenate the sign with balance

//similar process as above to get the start balance
stbal=${s:42:1}
stbal1=${s:27:15}

stbal2=$stbal1
stbal3=$stbal$stbal2

creditdebit="$(grep "${bban}" ${fileB} | awk '{array[substr($0,7,1)]+=substr($0,8,15)+0} END{for(i in array){print array[i]}}')"
set -- $creditdebit
... further logic
done < ${fileA}
```

Comment: FILE ..........

Comment: CAP letters usually treated as harsh, if it is a typo then please edit your post.

Comment: I just don't believe that awk script is taking too long to run. I also don't see how you're summing on a per-account basis. So, my money is on that you're calling that awk script repeatedly in a shell loop, once per account number, and THAT is what is taking a long time but we can't help you with that as you haven't shown that code to us.

Comment: yes am looping thru a file1 to get the account number first and then reading the file2 to get the summation of debit and credit which take more time is there a way out to make it more faster

Comment: OK so THAT is where your performance problem is. Show us a [mcve] with representative code for what you're doing including that missing part of it (the most important part!) so we can help you fix that code. Also show us the expected output given your posted sample input.

Comment: Include examples of fileA and fileB in the [mcve] and explain what the purpose of fileA is when the account numbers are already present in fileB.

Answer (score 1):

Without a complete MCVE its a guess but this might be what you're looking for, using GNU awk for true 2D arrays:

```
$ awk '
    { tots[substr($0,7,1)][substr($0,2,5)] += substr($0,8) }
    END {
        for (type in tots) {
            for (id in tots[type]) {
                print type, id, tots[type][id]+0
            }
        }
    }
' file
C 12345 129
C 23456 255
D 12345 129
D 23456 129
```

Answer (score 0):

in ksh you might do something like that : (myfile.txt being your information file)

```
#!/bin/ksh

typeset -A Ledger

typeset -i amount

typeset -L10 Col1
typeset -L10 Col2


while read line
do
        account=${line:1:5}
        action=${line:6:1}
        amount=${line:7:21}
        if [[ $action == "C" ]]; then
                Ledger[$account]=$(( ${Ledger[$account]} + $amount ))
        elif [[ $action == "D" ]]; then
                Ledger[$account]=$(( ${Ledger[$account]} - $amount ))
        fi
done < myfile.txt


Col1="Account"
Col2="Balance"


print "$Col1$Col2\n"

for i in ${!Ledger[@]}; do
        Col1=$i
        Col2=${Ledger[$i]}
        print "$Col1$Col2"
done
```

With your example my output is :

```
Account   Balance

12345     0
23456     126
```

Hope it could help